# check wordpress select box value

Tags: wordpress

How to check if a select box has  a value or not in wordpress by php?

I want to check if a select box has a value and if it has then  check the value against $post array generated by for-each loop.

Is there any built in wordpress function? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This function may be helpful for you:

```
selected( $selected, $current, $echo); 

$selected (required) = One of the values to compare.
Default: None

$current (optional) = The other value to compare if not just true.
Default: true

$echo(boolean) (optional) = Whether to echo or just return the string.
Default: true
```

Ref.link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use php function in wordpress actions for example:

```
    <select name="select_value">
      <option value="">Default value (key thing is leaving value="")</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

   //check in the action or filter for the drop-down value: 

    if($_POST['select_value'] != '') {
      //do something
      echo $_POST['select_value'];
    } else {
      //if not post any value
    }
```